# Linked StackOverflow blog posts should automatically convert to title

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, meta, blog

e.g. https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Should auto convert to [Gorilla vs. Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/), like SO posts do.

This will largely help meta, moreso than SO, but it would be helpful.

Comment: This would be great when writing comments (since there are no "short" urls for blog posts like there are for questions/answers)

Comment: There are. You can see them if you inspect the page source. For the post linked in the question, the short URL would be `http://blog.stackoverflow.com/?p=9324`, but I don't think it matters much anyway.

Comment: There are urls for comments, but they are not obvious , see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193594/improve-the-usability-intuitiveness-of-direct-comment-links