# How can I display a link to a specific comment in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

How can I display a link to a specific comment in Stack Overflow? Like how can I find the url?

Comment: It is right here ----->

Comment: @qwertynl - that's a link to your user :P

Comment: @Lix Ok fine **THIS** --->  ‮҉

Comment: @qwertynl - hehe... you got it! :D

Comment: @qwertynl - oh nice - your hat sits perfectly on your avatar :P

Comment: Direct comment links exist but should be more intuitive, e.g. having permalink icon - see
[Improve the usability/intuitiveness of direct comment links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280567)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the link address from the date that follows the username.

[image]

Comment: Pro Tip: *Most* of the timestamps on the site also act as permalinks. For example: On the question list page or on an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The link is on the right side of the comment.

Here is the comment that I made underneath your OP:

> `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213408/how-can-i-display-a-link-to-a-specific-comment-in-stack-overflow/213409#comment687139_213408`

Answer (score 0):

Click on the time it was posted ("1 min ago").