# Edit icon next to a comment is confusing on iPad (and other touch tablets)

Tags: feature-request, comments

I was working on iPad and noticed edit icon next  to a comment. I decided that I can edit these comments. I tapped on the button but nothing happened . Later on PC I found  a tooltip (not visible on the touch device ) explaining that comment was edited some time in the past.  iPads and other tablets as touch devices do not support tooltips, but have big enough screens to not use mobile theme.

It is confusing. Who cares what's happened a few years ago in a first five minutes after  creating of the comment.

I suggest to remove the icon or only keep it in the first hour since the comment was created.

Also the tooltip can be moved to Timestamp where it logically belongs. Timestamp tooltip can provide additional info, was comment changed(and may be when it was changed last time). Current implementation the timestamp as a permalink to the comment is not good, because timestamp and permalink are not logically related

Instead of this it's better to show permalink icon as suggested in question [Improve the usability/intuitiveness of direct comment links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193594/improve-the-usability-intuitiveness-of-direct-comment-links/280567#280567)

Update: After Shadow Wizard's answer I understand, that problem is not applicable for mobile devices with small screen. Should be created another "tablet" theme, that will support bigger screens, but wouldn't rely on tooltips?

Comment: Why downvote without reasoning?

Comment: Because people disagree with your feature request. Plain and simple. (Not me, I just now saw it and still processing.)

Comment: First impression: when on a mobile device, use the mobile web theme, that's what it's meant for. Click "mobile" in the footer and you'll enjoy a different design, tailored for mobile device with less "noise", and no tooltips. In the mobile web design, there is no pencil icon indeed, just like what you want.

Comment: I down voted because I think it is not confusing at all, and I disagree with the feature request.

Answer (score 3):

> Edit icon next to a comment is confusing

No, it's not confusing.

This icon is visible only on the full site theme, where it does have a clear tooltip. Users on mobile devices won't see it, unless switching to the full site by tapping the link in the footer, then they should know that things are going to look and act weird.

Unlike posts, comments don't have revisions. We can't see what changed and when, but knowing "something here changed" is still useful, same way it's useful to know something in a post changed.

I see no reason to remove this icon in the full site mode. (It's already removed in mobile web.)

---

As for the second request:

> Also the tooltip can be moved to Timestamp where it logically belongs

That would be even worse, and much more confusing, since the timestamp is a permalink to the comment. If anything, [it should reflect that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193594/improve-the-usability-intuitiveness-of-direct-comment-links).

Comment: 1. There are iPads and other tablets, that have big enough screens to not use mobile theme, but as touch devices do not support tooltips.       2."the timestamp is a permalink to the comment" is not a reason, because timestamp should NOT be a permalink to the comment -these things are not related. However timestamp can provide additional info, was comment changed(and also when it was changed last time)

Comment: Also I noticed that timestamp tooltip shows just time, so it can show changes info as well even being  permalink.