# More intuitive way of obtaining direct link to specific comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface, user-experience, permalink

Currently, it's not obvious how to obtain a link to a specific comment (there is no obvious share icon on comments).

[A question/answer on how to link to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/389220) has a lot of views/upvotes indicating a lot of people have had to go looking for how to link to a comment.

#### Suggestion

I could suggest changing from the current, e.g.

[image]

to something like

[image]

(only difference is the small link icon at the end of the comment, next to the edited icon)

Comment: The other question's accepted answer gives "right clicking on the timestamp" to give a URL. I don't get timestamps in my browser. (Not reliably at least, I do sometimes - another question I guess).

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. I think the answer is also incorrect (or at least outdated) since I must left click (I commented on the answer to that effect some time ago). Could be a/b testing or something I’m not privy to though. But overall I think the fact intelligent people can’t work it out without googling for it is a problem worth addressing in itself